# How to create a pie chart from my sql database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, charts, mariadb, pie-chart

I am trying to generate a pie chart using a maria mysql database, and I'm currently using for C#. I have searched a few examples but have not found a clear one. Currently my issue is when i run my program it show me only one information (Operations_Dept with 124000 in charttArea)

My table 
[image: table]

my image from my programme

[image: chart]

my code

```
public void LoadChart()
        {
            try
            {
                string allTables = " SELECT sum(Operations_Dept), sum(Operations_Cridet) FROM table_operations";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(allTables, ClassConn.MyConnection());
                ClassConn.OpenConnection();
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                chrt_ventes.Series["columns"].Points.Clear();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    this.chrt_ventes.Series["columns"].Points.AddXY( rdr[0], rdr[1]);

                }
                rdr.Close();
                ClassConn.CloseConnection();
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
```

Comment: Totally expected. You have one row and add one data point. I guess you want to add two of them.

Comment: He actually has a while loop and could display 5 rows.

Comment: Do note that a Pie can only display y-values, So do use AddY to add the data values. Does the reader loop as expected? I see none of the number in the table?!?

Comment: @TaW Have a look at the SQL. What do you think `sum` does?

Comment: Ah, right! Didn't expect this ;-) That also explains the values..

Comment: yes i want to show two of theme the sum(Operations_Dept), sum(Operations_Cridet) because is 2 must show one in lef and the second in right ....whay just one show with one color blue

Comment: I have no Idea what charting lib that is, but it looks to me if the "X" would be a label in the pie chart type diagram. So, you may want to `...Points.AddXY("Dept", rdr[0]);` and `...Points.AddXY("Cred",rdr[1]);` Have you tried that?

Comment: yes it's worked 100%

Comment: Ok, I would need to examine the docs for further help, I am afraid. What lib are you using?

Comment: it's worked sorry it's my mistake... how to make your answer as answer of this  Fildor !!!!!
thank you Fildor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is totally expected. You have one row and add one data point. I guess you want to add two of them.

Try

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     this.chrt_ventes.Series["columns"].Points.AddXY( "Dept" , rdr[0]);
     this.chrt_ventes.Series["columns"].Points.AddXY( "Cred" , rdr[1]);
}
```

Mind: This is untested; I have no idea what your charting lib is and how its API works. I just inferred this works from the result you are getting from that code.

Comment: im using a default lib of c# tools all the problem in coding thanks again
Fildor